# AngularJS: Is there a better way to sync two promises?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
$http.get('/services/menu').success(function (dataMenu) {
    $http.get('/services/language').success(function (dataLanguage) {
            console.log('dataLanguage', dataLanguage);
            $scope.menuRoot = dataMenu.result.items;
            $scope.menuItems = dataMenu.result.items;
            $scope.languageRoot = dataLanguage.result;
            $scope.currentMenuItem = null;
            $scope.refreshExperiments();
            $scope.mergeLanguage();
    });
});
```

Comment: You may want to have a look at [`$q.all`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$q) and [`$q.when`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$q).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes, you can run them in parallel by using [`$q.all`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24q#all):

```
$q.all([$http.get('/services/menu'), $http.get('/services/language')])
   .then(function (res) {
        var dataMenu = res[0].data.result.items;
        console.log('dataLanguage', res[1].data);
        $scope.menuRoot = dataMenu;
        $scope.menuItems = dataMenu;
        $scope.languageRoot = res[1].data.result;
        $scope.currentMenuItem = null;
        $scope.refreshExperiments();
        $scope.mergeLanguage();
});
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Notice the res contains another 'data' object so I edited it in.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively:

```
var menuPromise = $http.get('/services/menu');
var languagePromise = $http.get('/services/language');

menuPromise.success(function(dataMenu) {
    languagePromise.success(function(dataLanguage) {
        console.log('dataLanguage', dataLanguage);
        $scope.menuRoot = dataMenu.result.items;
        $scope.menuItems = dataMenu.result.items;
        $scope.languageRoot = dataLanguage.result;
        $scope.currentMenuItem = null;
        $scope.refreshExperiments();
        $scope.mergeLanguage();
    });
});
```

which makes both of the `$http` requests at the same time, and then runs the code block (`console.log... etc`) once both of the `$http` promises have been fulfilled.

Comment: Are you sure it would work? What if the languagePromise is finished before the languagePromise?

Comment: "...regardless of when the promise was or will be resolved or rejected, `then` calls one of the success or error callbacks asynchronously as soon as the result is available" -angular docs on `then`. ... 
I think `success` is just sugar for `then` so if the languagePromise is resolved first, it still won't be called until the menuPromise has been resolved